# Password Function on pyhon with using a while loop

Tags: python

i'm having some problems with this code wondering if anyone can help, i am a beg. 
 Open up `Unsolved/UserAdmin.py`.

2. Create a function named `getCreds` with no parameters that will prompt the user for their username and password. This function should return a dictionary called `userInfo` that looks like the dictionaries below:

```py
# Administrator accounts list
adminList = [
    {
        "username": "DaBigBoss",
        "password": "DaBest"
    },
    {
        "username": "root",
        "password": "toor"
    }
]
```

3. Create a function named `checkLogin` with two parameters: the `userInfo` and the `adminList`. The function should check the credentials to see if they are contained within the admin list of logins. The function should set a variable `loggedIn` to `True` if the credentials are found in the admin list, and set the variable to `False` otherwise.

Now that we know how to check to see if a user is logging in with admin credentials, let's set up the part of the system that will continue to prompt the user for their username and password if they didn't enter correct admin credentials before.

4. Create a `while` loop that will continue to call `getCreds` and `checkLogin` until a user logs in with admin credentials.
5. After each call of `checkLogin` in the `while` loop, print to the terminal the string `"---------"`.
6. Once the user logs in with admin credentials, print to the terminal the string `"YOU HAVE LOGGED IN!"`.
7. Run the code often as you write and test individual functions with correct and incorrect admin credentials to make sure you're on the right path!

this is the question i need help on

```
def getCreds():

    username = input("What is your username? ")
    password = input("What is your password? ")

    #
    userInfo = [
        {
            "username" : str(username), 
            "password" : str(password)
        }
    ]

    return userInfo

user_info = getCreds()

def checkLogin(adminList):

    if user_info in adminList:
        loggedIn = True
        print("yay")

    else: 
        loggedIn = False

    while loggedIn == False:
        print("Login Failed. ")
        retry = getCreds()
        return retry

getCreds()

checkLogin(user_info, adminList)
```

this is what i got. the loop is not working as intended, i cant get a postive result

Thank you in advance for anyone that can help

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take our [tour], it only takes a minute, I promise. Then, if you have any doubts, look at our [help].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely, on the right track, there are a couple of key issues that you've run into here.

Firstly, if you look carefully your getCreds function is returning a list with a single entry. The square brackets create the list the curly ones create the dictionary.

```py
>>> type([])
<class 'list'>
>>> type({})
<class 'dict'>
>>> type([{}])
<class 'list'>
```

This means that when you check `if user_info in admin_list`, you are seeing if a `list` object is in your `admin_list`, which we know contains only dictionaries. I think what you were looking to do is return just the dictionary from `getCreds`:

```py
def getCreds():
    ...
    return {"username": username, "password": password}
```

The next thing to be aware of is that the `return` statement exits the surrounding function, not a loop or if statement. So your `while` loop can only ever run once. You see two login prompts because of the one at the start of the function, and then the first iteration of that loop before it exists. The `break` statement is the one that exits the current loop.

It also sounds like what you set of problems is looking for, though is for the while loop to exist outside of either function:

```py
def getCreds():
    # returns user info dictionary
    ...

def checkLogin(admin_list, user_info):
    # returns True or False
    ...


while True:
    user_info = getCreds()
    is_admin = checkLogin(admin_list, user_info)
    print("---------")
    if is_admin:
        print("YOU HAVE LOGGED IN!")
        break
```

One final note on security, usually you do not want the user's password to be visible in the terminal as they type it. The `getpass` function from the `getpass` standard library module provides an easy way to read in sensitive data like a password and will work as a drop-in replacement for the built-in `input` function:

```py
# at the top of the whole file
from getpass import getpass

...

username = input("username: ")
password = getpass("password: ")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
adminList = [
    {
        "username": "DaBigBoss",
        "password": "DaBest"
    },
    {
        "username": "root",
        "password": "toor"
    }
]

def getCreds():

    username = input("What is your username? ")
    password = input("What is your password? ")


    userInfo = [
        {
            "username" : (username), 
            "password" : (password)
        }
    ]

    return userInfo

user_info = getCreds()

def checkLogin(adminList, user_info):
    user_info = getCreds()
    if user_info in adminList:
        loggedIn = True
        print("you've logged in!")

    else :
        loggedIn = False
    while loggedIn == False:
        print("Login Failed. ")
        print("---------")
        retry = getCreds()
        return retry

getCreds()

checkLogin(adminList, user_info)
```

output

```
  What is your username? root
What is your password? toor
What is your username? root
What is your password? toor
What is your username? root
What is your password? toor
Login Failed.
---------
What is your username?
```

this is what i'm getting

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for you help this is what im coming up with! Seems to be wokring find just the loop is never ending which isnt a big deal! thank you so much again for everyones help

```
adminList = [
        {
            "username": "DaBigBoss",
            "password": "DaBest"
        },
        {
            "username": "root",
            "password": "toor"
        }
    ]


    # Build your login functions below
    def getCreds():
        username = input("What is your username? ")
        password = input("What is your password? ")




    return {"username": username, "password": password}


def checkLogin(adminList, user_info):
    if user_info in adminList:
        loggedIn = True
        print("YOU HAVE LOGGED IN")
    else: 
        loggedIn = False
        print("------")
        print("Login Failed")
        print("------")
        retry = getCreds()
        return 


while True:
    user_info = getCreds()
    is_admin = checkLogin(adminList, user_info)
    print("-----")
    if is_admin:
        print("YOU HAVE LOGGED IN!")
        break
    else:
        ("login Failed please try again")
```